# Apache web not accessible on LAN

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm trying to make a small little web page that runs on my local network. I'm using WAMP and running Apache. When I put `localhost` or my IP in the address bar on the computer where I'm hosting it, it works fine, as expected. But, when I try to go there from my phone or any other device on my network, it just hangs, and eventually says that the site can't be reached. I'm assuming that this is either a problem with a setting in Apache, or a setting on my PC, but I'm not sure which.

Here's a screenshot of what I get on my PC:
[image]

And here's one of what I get on my phone. The same happens with any other device.
[image]

If it helps, the page I'm trying to access is a Python cgi file. I have made sure that Apache is configured correctly to run this file.

Comment: are your network discovery and sharing settings configured to allow other devices to access resources on your computer?

Comment: @mael' Just checked what I think you mean, and I have "Turn on network discovery" enabled for both the public and private profiles.

Comment: Are you using the ipaddress of the host pc or are you trying to use a domain name.

Answer (score 2):

The first place I would start troubleshooting is in you Apache configuration files. In general, I would:

- Make certain that `httpd.conf` had a generic `Listen 80` directive (rather than e.g. `Listen 127.0.0.1:80`).
- Ensure there were no `Require ip` or `Require local` directives, either in `httpd.conf` or in your virtual host(s). In particular, I would look for them under any `<Directory>` entries for `www` or `cgi-bin` (or whatever directories you are using  in place of these).
- Anything referencing `localhost` may also be an issue.

More broadly, you may want to have WAMP in Online mode (I believe) and make certain Apache/WAMP is allowed through your local host's firewall (Windows firewall).

Comment: I changed to XAMPP for my Apache server, and its working fine. If I ever try to use WAMP for this again, I will 100% try your suggestions. Thanks! By the way, should I edit my question to say that my problem is more-or-less fixed?

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear switching helped sort out the configuration issues. You can certainly edit the question to note you fixed the situation by installing XAMPP. It may give someone else a quick fix.

Comment: Just as a thought, if your solution is more than a simple note, you should consider posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me Windows 11 firewall was blocking access. I had to whitelist the httpd.exe file in Windows Defender.